# Swift types cannot implicitly conform to Encodable if it has a 'any Encodable' property

Tags: swift

I was trying to implement a type that conforms to `Encodable` and has a `any encodable` property like this:

```swift
struct Foo : Encodable {
    
    var anyEncodableValue : any Encodable

}
```

But the complier would complain with this error message:
`Type 'Foo' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'`

To solve this problem, I must implement `encode` function in `Foo` as follow:

```swift
    private enum FooCodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case anyEncodableValue
    }
    
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: FooCodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(anyEncodableValue, forKey: .anyEncodableValue)
    }
```

My question is, why does my type `Foo` not implicitly conform to `Encodable`? To be clear the following is what I mean by "implicitly conforms to `Encodable`":

```
struct Bar : Encodable {
    var a : Int
    var b : String    

    // no need to implement func encode(to encoder: Encoder)
}
```

Comment: `Encodable` implementation will only be generated if every stored property's type conforms to `Encodable`. `any Encodable` does not conform to `Encodable`. See the dupe target for more info.